# Why was this question about using the ASP.NET pipeline to serve contextual content closed as OT?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

With reference to the below question, I'm interested to know why it was closed.

The question seems to me to be asking how to use ASP.NET MVC to serve content in response to an http request that differs depending on context (in this case the host name). Is that really off-topic for stackoverflow?

> [robots.txt file for different domains of same site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033779/robots-txt-file-for-different-domains-of-same-site)

As a comparison, if this question is off-topic, wouldn't asking how to serve different language content based on the domain also be off-topic, as in:

> [How to get "Host:" header from HttpContext (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638669/how-to-get-host-header-from-httpcontext-asp-net)

We should at least be consistent?

(*With (a lot of) respect to the (very high rep) <strike>mods</strike> users that closed it, none of them have any .NET languages or ASP.NET MVC in their top ten tags, maybe they misunderstood that this is exactly the kind of problem that the ASP.NET pipeline is there to solve?*)

Comment: For reference, it wasn't closed by mods, it was community closed by site users. Mods have a Diamond ♦ after their name.

Comment: @JonW. Thank you, corrected.

Comment: It does not sound on-topic, it sounds like a webserver question, which is better suited on SF. Maybe a rewording and polishing might help?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby. I would definitely agree with rewording and polishing, but its definitely a programming question - the solution would be implemented in the chosen .NET language in visual studio, not on IIS (I would look at it like: "_if this is a webserver question, so is any asp.net mvc question on SO_").

Comment: What I wanted to say is *it sounds like a webserver question*, and that is most likely why it was closed as off-topic. Edit, reword, polish, vote to reopen.

Comment: Robo-closers, following the lead of one single user who flagged for closure.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby. My bad, I understood that - and I agree it should be worded better. (_OT: Awesome profile statement, made my morning_)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why the community closed it as off-topic.

I see that it was [found in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2294910); it looks like that's where it was closed from.

I also don't believe you need experience in a tag in order to close something as Off topic. If that were the case, there'd be very few moderators qualified to handle each major tag.

I've re-opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033779/robots-txt-file-for-different-domains-of-same-site) because it *is* on topic.

In the future, you can flag the question for re-opening. Please include your reasoning.  To do this:

- Click "Flag"
- Click "Other"
- Include reasoning for re-opening.

If we don't mark your flag as 'helpful', or don't act on it, then coming to meta would be the best bet.

Comment: Thank you George, I didn't _think_ I [had enough rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) to flag for reopen, now I see there is a difference between voting to reopen and flagging to ask someone else to do the reopening.